# Octave Create Matrices with For Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, matrix, octave, zero

i need your insight. I want to create 20 different zero matrices, like this:

```
metrics_1 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_2 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_3 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_4 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_5 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_6 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_7 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_8 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_9 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_10 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_11 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_12 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_13 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_14 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_15 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_16 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_17 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_18 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_19 = zeros(10, 19);
metrics_20 = zeros(10, 19);
```

How can i do this faster with a for loop?

Thanks a lot

Comment: the answers below give much more efficient ways of creating/storing these matrices, but is there a particular reason you want to create multiple sequentially named variables? while you're talking about Octave, this Matlab article still applies in many ways:  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean "more easily"?

Instead of creating **20** 2d arrays of size 10x19, you just have to create one single 3d array of size 10x19x**20**

`metrics = zeros(10,19,20);`

Then, instead of accessing `metrics_8(:,:)`, you will access `metrics(:,:,8)`

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to do a 3D matrix [as suggested by PierU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75881369/7328782), you can make a cell array. Instead of `metrics_8`, you’d do `metrics{8}`. You can create it as follows:

```matlab
metrics = cell(20,1);
for i = 1:numel(metrics)
   metrics{i} = zeros(10, 19);
end
```

In this case, each matrix can have a different size. If they are always the same size, the 3D array approach is more efficient with memory.

A shortcut to fill all elements of a cell array with a copy of the same array is:

```matlab
metrics = cell(20,1);
[metrics{:}] = deal(zeros(10, 19));
```